# The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable"

Tags: vba

```
Sub CountryPopList()
    ' declare the variables
    Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim i As Integer

    ' initialize i to one
    i = 1

    ' create and get access to an instance of IE
    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    ieObj.Visible = True
    ieObj.navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-announcements"

    ' give the webpage some time to load all content
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    ' loop through all the rows in the table
    For Each htmlEle In ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("table-CFanncEquity")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
            .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
            .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(2).textContent
            .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
            .Range("E" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(4).textContent
        End With

        i = i + 1
    Next htmlEle

End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to scraping the website thorugh  vba "https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-announcements" but  the system always give me error "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable". Can anyone please help to scraping for this website ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `getElementsByClassName()` when you need `getElementById()`
This worked for me:

```
Sub CountryPopList()
    ' declare the variables
    Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim i As Integer, tbl

    ' initialize i to one
    i = 1

    ' create and get access to an instance of IE
    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    ieObj.Visible = True
    ieObj.navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-announcements"

    ' give the webpage some time to load all content
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    ' loop through all the rows in the table
    Set tbl = ieObj.document.getElementById("table-CFanncEquity")
    For Each htmlEle In tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
            .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
            .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(2).textContent
            .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
            .Range("E" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(4).textContent
        End With

        i = i + 1
    Next htmlEle

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for response. However I tried this coding as well but still getting same error. for " Set tbl = ieObj.document.getElementById("table-CFanncEquity")" line.